# Cross-Compiling gcc failure (Python)

Tags: python, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile Python to port over to a router (ASUS RT-N16) with DD-WRT (DD-WRT v24-sp2 (SVN revision: 14896)) on it. JFFS2 (and therefore ipkg) and Optware are not options. I need to do a straight cross-compile. I'm new to cross-compiling.

I tried following these directions:
  http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/02/04/cross-compiling-python-for-mips-and-arm-platforms/

I also tried these directions but got the same errors (this is what I JUST finished doing):
http://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean9/ean9-howto-newlib-1.0.pdf

But I keep getting the following:

```
majik@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.3$ sudo CC=mipsel-linux-gcc CXX=mipsel-linux-g++ AR=mipsel-linux-ar RANLIB=mipsel-linux-ranlib ./configure -host=mipsel-linux -target=mipsel-linux -prefix=/python
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux2
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... i686
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for mipsel-linux-gcc... mipsel-linux-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/majik/Desktop/Python-2.7.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

My config.log contains the following:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 2.7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.67.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure -host=mipsel-linux -target=mipsel-linux -prefix=/python

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ubuntu
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.2.0-37-generic-pae
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:51:02 UTC 2013

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2756: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:2797: result: no
configure:2806: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:2823: result: 32-bit
configure:2980: checking MACHDEP
configure:3129: result: linux2
configure:3135: checking EXTRAPLATDIR
configure:3150: result: 
configure:3161: checking machine type as reported by uname -m
configure:3164: result: i686
configure:3177: checking for --without-gcc
configure:3221: result: no
configure:3242: checking for mipsel-linux-gcc
configure:3269: result: mipsel-linux-gcc
configure:3538: checking for C compiler version
configure:3547: mipsel-linux-gcc --version >&5
./configure: line 3549: mipsel-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3558: $? = 127
configure:3547: mipsel-linux-gcc -v >&5
./configure: line 3549: mipsel-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3558: $? = 127
configure:3547: mipsel-linux-gcc -V >&5
./configure: line 3549: mipsel-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3558: $? = 127
configure:3547: mipsel-linux-gcc -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3549: mipsel-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3558: $? = 127
configure:3578: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3600: mipsel-linux-gcc    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3602: mipsel-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3604: $? = 127
configure:3642: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _BSD_TYPES 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
| #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3647: error: in `/home/majik/Desktop/Python-2.7.3':
configure:3649: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=mipsel-linux-gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=mipsel-linux
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=mipsel-linux
ac_cv_prog_CC=mipsel-linux-gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='mipsel-linux-ar'
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='mipsel-linux-gcc'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=' '\''-host=mipsel-linux'\'' '\''-target=mipsel-linux'\'' '\''-prefix=/python'\'' '\''host_alias=mipsel-linux'\'' '\''target_alias=mipsel-linux'\'' '\''CC=mipsel-linux-gcc'\'''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='mipsel-linux-g++'
DEFS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXTRAMACHDEPPATH=''
EXTRAPLATDIR=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLAPPSPREFIX=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKUNIXTOOLSPREFIX='/python'
GNULD=''
GREP=''
HAS_HG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG=''
HGBRANCH=''
HGTAG=''
HGVERSION=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTSONAME=''
LDCXXSHARED=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDLAST=''
LDLIBRARY=''
LDLIBRARYDIR=''
LDSHARED=''
LIBC=''
LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBM=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBRARY=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL_CRUFT=''
LINKCC=''
LINKFORSHARED=''
LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS=''
LN=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MACHDEP='linux2'
MACHDEP_OBJS=''
MAINCC=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT=''
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://bugs.python.org/'
PACKAGE_NAME='python'
PACKAGE_STRING='python 2.7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='python'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORK=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR='no-framework'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER='org.python.python'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX=''
RANLIB='mipsel-linux-ranlib'
RUNSHARED=''
SGI_ABI=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIBS=''
SIGNAL_OBJS=''
SO=''
SOVERSION='1.0'
SRCDIRS=''
SVNVERSION=''
THREADHEADERS=''
THREADOBJ=''
TRUE=''
UNICODE_OBJS=''
UNIVERSALSDK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCH_FLAGS=''
USE_SIGNAL_MODULE=''
USE_THREAD_MODULE=''
VERSION='2.7'
ac_ct_CC=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias='mipsel-linux'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/python'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias='mipsel-linux'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _BSD_TYPES 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

configure: exit 77
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have the system that I'm trying to compile on, but I do not have access to the router unless I'm at work (won't be back there until next Tuesday). But It's the cross-compiler that's the problem. From what I understand, once it's all compiled, the folder just needs to be copied (via scp) to the router. Thanks!

~BB

Comment: This looks interesting: `mipsel-linux-gcc: command not found`. Also, are you positive that the router has enough resources to run Python 2.7?

Comment: I'd suggest doing hello.c (i.e. the bareminimum c program) and verify you can run mipsel-linux-gcc against it to produce a mips binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to know if you have install mipel-gcc cross compiler on your desktop.

Since routers have mipsel architecture, MIPS architecture with Little Endian (MIPSEL) format. You have to install mipsel-gcc cross compiler before compiling the python code in that architecture. Once you have compiler the code, you can run the code on your router.

Once you have installed mipsel, you can add it to you path variables and the code will work.